# Receiving a "module not found" and "field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration" deploying my site to Netlify

Tags: node-modules, gatsby, netlify

My GatsbyJS site runs fine locally but does not produce a successful build when deploying to Netlify. I've researched the error I'm receiving and haven't had any luck. Changing the case of the file name or changing the file path doesn't work.

[image: Image 1 of build fail]
[image: Image 2 of build fail]

[Link to repository](https://github.com/celinefucci/cf-website)

Comment: Just a quick help comment: The images can be embedded in the question rather than linked or just copy the text directly to a code block for easy reading. It really helps you get a quicker answer and also makes it easy for the person giving the answer. When it is answered, you can mark the answer. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I marked the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your local machine, run the command `gatsby build` will result in the error you show in the images.

You will notice the error lines:

```
Error: ./src/components/header.js
... Can't resolve 'components/variables.css' in ...

opt/build/repo/node_modules/components/variables.css doesn't exist
```

tells you it is trying to resolve the `components/variables.css` as a module in your project.

### Solution

Change the import line for `variables.css` in `header.js`:

`src/components/header.js`

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import 'components/variables.css'
...
```

to the following:

`src/components/header.js`

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import './variables.css'
...
```

Comment: It actually worked. I changed the path in variables.css like you said and also had to change the path in header.js to: import Header from '../components/header.js' After 10 or more failed built attempts, it finally worked. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure netlify knows what version of node you need to build your app.
https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/#build-environment-variables

Also make sure your project is able to build from scratch. Clone the repository into a new directory and try to build it.